# Is the inverse of Armstrong's Axioms valid as well?

Tags: database-design, relations, dependencies

I have been looking into Armstrong's axioms a little bit. In a homework[1] exercise I was asked to prove A→G is in F-closure. I managed to get it at this point:

```
AB → GB
```

Being at this point, can I simply say that A → G as it seems pretty straightforward or do I have to go through certain steps as well. As Armstrong's axiom states:

```
if X → Y then XZ → YZ
```

Would the inverse be true as well ?

```
if XZ → YZ then X → Y  <-- ?
```

*[1] I don't think the content of the homework does relate in here*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the inverse is not true. The assumption:

```
if XZ → YZ then X → Y
```

is false.

You could have only `XZ → Y` for example, from which you can infer `XZ → YZ` and a few others. But not `X → Y`.

Answer (score 4):

No, that is not true.

[Armstrong's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms) are a sound and complete  axiomatization of the logical implication for [functional dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency).

Here is a relation, where the functional dependency `XZ → YZ` holds:

```
X  Y  Z
--------
x1 y1 z1
x2 y1 z1
x1 y2 z2
x2 y2 z2
```

But the functional dependency `X → Y` does not hold, as the tuples `x1 y1 z1` and `x1 y2 z2` show. Because of the soundness of Armstrong's axioms, which means that only valid functional dependencies can be derived, the "inverse" is not true. So we have constructed a counterexample.

---

If this "inverse" law would hold, then we can show that `X → Y` for arbitrary attribute sets `X` and `Y`:

```
Y → Y      (reflexivity)
XY → XY    (augmentation)
XY → Y     (reflexivity)
XY → YY    (idempodency of union-operator: Y=YY)
X → Y      ("inverse")
```